# Model methods in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, activerecord

I have the following piece of code in my view:

```
<% if @user.get_products.any? %>
  <%= f.select('products', @user.get_products.collect { |user| [user.name, user.id]}) %>
```

Where `get_products` is making an `ActiveRecord` query to DB. So I wonder if it actually does two same queries or uses cached result from first query on second call? I tried to check it in server logs - but found nothing. I would also like to know if I can control this behavior somehow, i.e. set/unset cache for this view.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

I think it violates MVC too, but what confused me was IDE warning: "view should not share more than two variables with controller."

However, I am creating somewhat "one page" website, so I need to have `@user`, `@nearest_users`, and `@user_products` in the same view. So I found the following article:
http://matthewpaulmoore.com/post/5190436725/ruby-on-rails-code-quality-checklist#instances

which said

> Only one or two instance variables are shared between each controller
>   and view.
>
> Instance variable hell - when a lot of instance variables are shared
>   between a controller and a view - is easy to do in Rails.  It’s also
>   potentially dangerous to performance, because you can end up making
>   duplicate calls on associations unknowingly.  Instead, your controller
>   should only manage one instance variable - and perhaps a second for
>   the current_user.  That way, all calls to associations are loaded “on
>   demand”, and can be instance-variable-cached in a single place.
>
> This methodology also works out well for fragment caching, because you
>   can check caches in views before actually loading associations.
>
> For example, instead of having your Blog controller create an instance
>   variable for both @post and @related_posts, just make a single method,
>   @post, and give your Post model a related_posts method, so you can
>   just call @post.related_posts in your views.

Comment: This is generally seen as a bad practice because it violates MVC and Liskov substitution. Try accessing ActiveRecord with your controller  or a helper. Maybe you should assign @products and you might find the issue with finer grained tests.

Comment: if you look at your server logs you should see the query in blue for queried and purple for cached. The convention is to just use `products` and not `get_products` btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question: **Queries in view don't get cached.**

What's more, Ruby codes in ERB template are executed using `eval`, which is very inefficient.

So my advice is: avoid writing logic in view, it's kind of bad practice.

Comment: I learned this from a slide in RubyConf China 2012. You may not read Chinese, but in case you did, here is the slide: http://blog.xdite.net/posts/2012/11/20/rubyconf-china-2012-ten-slow-things-you-dont-know/